# What is the best way to write mocha unit tests when Node.js required modules need to be stubbed/mocked?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

```
var config = require('../config/config');
var dynasty = require('dynasty')(config);

dynasty.list('name').then(function(resp) {
    console.log(resp);
});
```

I've tried using libraries like Sinon, proxyquire and mockery but have been unsuccessful.

Also what does require('dynasty')(config) mean? I know it's passing in the values stored in the variable config, but is there any other way to achieve this, or to pass this value while using one of the testing libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be unusual for that code to be on it's own. What you will normally do is have some sort of service wrapper, maybe something like this:

```
function MyService(db) {
  this._db = db;
}

MyService.prototype.getList = function (name) {
  return db.list(name);
}

module.exports = MyService;
```

Now you can write a unit test that can look something like this:

```
var assert = require('assert');
var MyService = require('./MyService');

describe('MyService', function () {
  it('should return a list', function () {
    var resolvingDb = {
      list: function () {
        return Promise.resolve([]);
      }
    };
    var instance = new MyService(resolvingDb);

    return instance.getList()
      .then(function (results) {
        assert(Array.isArray(results), 'should return db.list');
      });
  });
});
```

You use a unit test to just test the logic in your service.

You'd also write an integration test in a separate file which uses a real instance of your database connector.

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

If your module has a constructor or it is possible for you to do it this way, and takes the modules as constructor arguments in order to inject it in your test, you can just provided a stubbed/mocked implementation of your modules in your test.